# VS2010 trying to load an unreferenced assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Before I explain the actual problem, for some unknown length of time, VS2010 has not been set to break on a CLR exception. I hadn't noticed this until recently when I discovered an error by using the app. How that option was turned of is a mystery to me. This may or may not be relevant to the following.

Now that I have the CLR exceptions being thrown, the below detailed exception halts VS2010 at the following:

```
  using (UnitOfWork uow22 = new UnitOfWork())
  {
    bool useWebInt = uow22.Query<MCCommon.Web>().Where(o => o.Enabled == true).Select(o => o.OfflineEnabled).FirstOrDefault(); // <--- causes the exception
    enabled = useWebInt;
  }
```

Any user of DevExpress will recognise the XPO UnitOfWork and know it's contained in a DevEx dll. The object MCCommon.Web is contained in a dll that is properly referenced in the project.MCCommon nor MCCommon.Web have no references to MyCourtsAdmin.

Here's the error generated by the above code segment:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException occurred
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'MyCourtsAdmin' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
  Source=mscorlib
  FileName=MyCourtsAdmin
  FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = KATOOMBA\Administrator
LOG: DisplayName = MyCourtsAdmin
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: MyCourtsAdmin | Domain ID: 1
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : DevExpress.Data.v11.2, Version=11.2.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\My Projects\MyCourts\bin\Debug\MyCourts.vshost.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/MyCourtsAdmin.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/MyCourtsAdmin/MyCourtsAdmin.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/bin/DLLs/MyCourtsAdmin.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/bin/DLLs/MyCourtsAdmin/MyCourtsAdmin.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/MyCourtsAdmin.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/MyCourtsAdmin/MyCourtsAdmin.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/bin/DLLs/MyCourtsAdmin.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Documents/My Projects/MyCourts/bin/Debug/bin/DLLs/MyCourtsAdmin/MyCourtsAdmin.EXE.

  StackTrace:
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
       at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.LoadWithPartialNameInternal(AssemblyName an, Evidence securityEvidence, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  InnerException:
```

Now MyCourtsAdmin (as referenced in the error) is a separate project altogether and is neither referenced by my project nor the MCCommon dll. MyCourtsAdmin does reference MCCommon however there are no bi-lateral references.

I have searched the whole directory structure of my project for a string 'MyCourtsAdmin' and the only reference I can find is in myproject.suo . I can't of course edit myproject.suo and I don't believe I should have to.

I'm stumped and would appreciate any/all input to solving this issue.

Comment: I should add, the function in question works fine - or at least it seems to.

Comment: You misunderstand what the Thrown checkbox does in that dialog.  Having them off is the *normal* way.  When you turn it on, you'll get to see *all* exceptions, including the ones that normally get handled by code you didn't write.

Comment: @Hans Passant I was starting to think that might be the case. Thanks